# How to use a mmap file mapping for variables

Tags: c, unix, memory-management, ipc, mmap

I'm currently experimenting with IPC via mmap on Unix.

So far, I'm able to map a sparse-file of 10MB into the RAM and access it reading and writing from two separated processes. Awesome :)

Now, I'm currently typecasting the address of the memory-segment returned by mmap to char*, so I can use it as a plain old cstring.

Now, my real question digs a bit further. I've quite a lot experience with higher levels of programming (ruby, java), but never did larger projects in C or ASM.

I want to use the mapped memory as an address-space for variable-allocation. I dont't wether this is possible or does make any sense at all. Im thinking of some kind of a hash-map-like data structure, that lives purely in the shared segment. This would allow some interesting experiments with IPC, even with other languages like ruby over FFI.

Now, a regular implementation of a hash would use pretty often something like malloc. But this woult allocate memory out of the shared space.

I hope, you understand my thoughts, although my english is not the best!

Thank you in advance
Jakob

Answer (score 1):

By and large, you can treat the memory returned by `mmap` like memory returned by `malloc`. However, since the memory may be shared between multiple "unrelated" processes, with independent calls to `mmap`, the starting address for each may be different. Thus, any data structure you build inside the shared memory should not use direct pointers.

Instead of pointers, offsets from the initial map address should be used instead. The data structure would then compute the right pointer value by adding the offset to the starting address of the `mmamp` region.

The data structure would be built from the single call to `mmap`. If you need to grow the data structure, you have to extend the `mmap` region itself. The could be done with `mremap` or by manually `munmap` and `mmap` again after the backing file has been extended.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response.  I think, I meant another point with my question. I have problems wrapping my head around creating linked objects dynamically in the shared memory-region. So, every dynamically created struct is linked (by relative addresses) and accessible for every participating process.

Comment: You can't use pointers, and all the "dynamic" memory has to come from the same `mmap` region, as I explained. Use offsets in place of a pointer, and compute the pointer value when the pointer is needed. Grow the file and remap it to allocate more memory.